# Chrome for iOS doesn't trigger css3 animations using waypoints until the scroll has stopped

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-waypoints

I'm using jquery waypoints to trigger css3 animations when the element is 75% in the viewport. This works great on desktop clients and safari on iOS but not for chrome on iOS. The animation will only trigger when the scroll has stopped. This is fine is the user is slowly scrolling but if they scroll past a section and do not stop the animation does not get triggered. Has anyone else has this issue?

My current solution is to detect if the device is a touch device and if so disable the animation making everything 100% opacity, but it seems a shame as it worked well in safari iOS.

Comment: I just tried a very similar interaction I made on Chrome for iOS and it worked well. Some additional specifics would be good like what CSS animation property isnt working? IF you could post code, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers on iOS do not actively measure the scroll position when a user is scrolling through the page. When a user is scrolling through a page on desktop, their position is constantly being measured, however, on an iOS device the position is only measured once they have stopped scrolling.

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way around this. Best to deactivate for mobile or create an interaction that isnt heavily effected by this issue.